# XSL-FO: "snaking" index across two columns (XEP)

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo

Using XSL-FO XEP I have created a simple index for my project. The index is 2 columns. But the content does not "snake" from the bottom left to top right column. Instead the content just continues from page to page in the left column. I haven't been able to find solution to this.

The XSL-FO is quite simple and entirely separate from the rest of the document:`@column-count` is in `fo:simple-page-master/fo:region-body`. At the moment I only have one `fo:simple-page-master` for the entire index.

```
<!-- simple page masters -->
<fo:simple-page-master master-name="all-recto"
                page-height="29.7cm"  page-width="21cm"
                margin-top="3cm" margin-bottom="2cm" 
                margin-left="3cm" margin-right="1.5cm">
  <fo:region-body column-count="2"/>
  <fo:region-after extent="12pt" padding-top="2cm"/>
</fo:simple-page-master>
```

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

CORRECTION: the content "snakes" from left to right column only on the very last page (after 50 pages)!

Comment: I  have solved the problem by removing the `keep-with-previous.within-page` in the content blocks...

Comment: yes, that's the typical symptom of setting keep-with to "always". Set it to a number instead of you want content to keep with previous without overflowing.